# JavaScript Errors when using ColorBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

Here's a couple of screenshots of errors I'm receiving:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbPW7.jpg

The errors read:
"Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new p.fn.init(a,b,c)} has no method 'colorbox'"

"Uncaught TypeError; object is not a function"

```
    <script>

    $("document").ready(function (){ 

           // load the overlay

            if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) {
                var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*15;
                var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
                document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
                $.colorbox({width:"580px", inline:true, href:"#subscribe_popup"});
            }

            $(".open_popup").colorbox({width:"580px", inline:true, href:"#subscribe_popup"});

     });


    </script>
```

I'm using Colorbox v.1.3.16 & jQuery v.1.8.2

Comment: Try including the plugins as separate files instead of one combined file. Use the unminified version(s) if you want to narrow down exactly where the code is failing.